# SWT version of: getOppositeComponent on focus change

Tags: java, swt

In Swing you can get "the other Component involved in this focus change" from this: [getOppositeComponent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html#getOppositeComponent()). There does not seem to be a similar call in SWT, does anyone have a workaround or fix for this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent for that in SWT, but you can try to use the following lists on both components:

```
public class OppositeAwareFocusListener implements FocusListener {
  Widget opposite;
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    ..
  }
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    this.opposite = e.widget;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly: you should instead have a `FocusListener` on the widget you wish to observe lost focus.

Comment: Unfortunately, the algorithm is in focusLost(...) so this will not help.

Comment: You can move that code into the focusGained() where you have access to both widgets.

Comment: But then what happens when the user clicks somewhere outside of the program? Or even in the program but not on a specific widget (e.g. a Composite)? The widget has lost focus and no one else has fired the focus gained event - thus no validation.